# Place a custom post type under a custom menu items

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

I'm trying to place a custom post type under the menus I made, Here is the screenshot of the menus. I want to add the custom post type together with that Menus. I used sandbox_theme_menu, but the custom post type is not appearing,

I tried adding this line in my register_post_type but still not appearing. Hmm any idea?

```
'show_in_menu' => 'edit.php?page=sandbox_theme_menu',
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The problem comes because **custom post_types** should be created on WP init, but custom menu items cannot be added before the `admin_menu` hook.

While you know the position of the post_type in the menu, you can force it to be placed in another menu like this

Creating a new top menu item :

```
<?php
add_action('admin_menu', 'add_menu');
function add_menu(){
    add_menu_page(
        'Menu name',
        'Menu name',
        'publish',
        'your_menu_slug',
        'your_function_name'
    );
}
?>
```

creating a custom post type :
(I only put here usefull parameters for the example)

```
<?php
add_action('init', 'create_cpt');
function create_cpt(){
    register_post_type(
        'your_cpt',
        array(
        'label' => 'Your CPT',
        'show_ui' => true,
        'show_in_menu' => true,
        'menu_position' => 901 //(or any not used numeric value)
        )
    );
}
?>
```

At this point, your menu should show an item for the custom post type and another one for the custom page.
To move the custom post type under the custom page, add change the add_menu function like this :

```
<?php
function add_menu(){
    add_menu_page(
        'Menu name',
        'Menu name',
        'publish',
        'your_menu_slug',
        'your_function_name'
    );
// get the global menu object
    global $menu,$submenu;
// Add the top menu item to your custom page
    $submenu['your_menu_slug'][] =  $menu[901]; 
     //(must be the same numeric value as in register_post_type)
// Finnaly, remove the initial menu item
    unset($menu[901]);
}
?>
```

Now your custom post type should appear under the custom page menu item.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use

```
'show_ui' => true
```

as an argument to register_post_type function to make 'show_in_menu' work. More information is available [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type).